# How to observe the url in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How to capture the user id when some one logs in

while running this code in my whole application its not capturing the user id but if i give it manually its working fine

i wrote code for user login in server when loading the app the ui is not capturing the id which is in server

its showing this error
Error in as.character(function (description, open = "", blocking = TRUE,  :
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

so is there any way to observe the url or late the working of action button so that it will capture the user_id when user logs in

```
library(shiny)
    library(shiny)

u_id<-"333"
inv_id <-222
url <- paste0("https://www.google.com/","?id=",u_id, "&inv_id=", inv_id)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("url function"),
  
  # Sidebar with an actionButton with the onclick parameter
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("ab1",
                   label = "ADD COMMENT",
                   icon = icon("ab1"),
                   onclick = sprintf("window.open('%s','win','resizable,height=400,width=400')",url)) # Combine text with url variable
 # Combine text with url variable
      # Use the onclick parameter to open a new window to the twitter url
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```